# Using signalR to update Winforms UI

Tags: asynchronous, signalr, signalr.client

I have a form that was created on it's own UI thread running in the system tray which I need to manipulate with a signalR connection from the server which I believe to be running on a background thread. I'm aware of the need to invoke controls when not accessing them from their UI thread. I am able to manipulate (make popup in my case) using the following code that is called on form load but would like a sanity check as I'm fairly new to async:

```
 private void WireUpTransport()
    {
        // connect up to the signalR server
        var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:32957/");
        var messageHub = connection.CreateProxy("message");
        var uiThreadScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

        var backgroundTask = connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an error opening the connection: {0}", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The connection was opened successfully");
            }
        });

        // subscribe to the servers Broadcast method
        messageHub.On<Domain.Message>("Broadcast", message =>
        {
            // do our work on the UI thread
            var uiTask = backgroundTask.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                popupNotifier.TitleText = message.Title + ", Priority: " + message.Priority.ToString();
                popupNotifier.ContentText = message.Body;
                popupNotifier.Popup();
            }, uiThreadScheduler);
        });
    }
```

Does this look OK? It's working on my local machine but this has the potential to be rolled out on every user machine in our business and I need to get it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically you should hook up to all notifications (using `On<T>`) before you `Start` listening. As far as your async work I'm not quite sure what you were trying to do, but for some reason your chaining the notification to your UI in `On<T>` to the `backgroundTask` variable which is the Task that was returned to you by the call to `Start`. There's no reason for that to be involved there.

So this is probably what you want:

```
private void WireUpTransport()
{
    // connect up to the signalR server
    var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:32957/");
    var messageHub = connection.CreateProxy("message");
    var uiTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    // subscribe to the servers Broadcast method
    messageHub.On<Domain.Message>("Broadcast", message =>
    {
        // do our work on the UI thread
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                popupNotifier.TitleText = message.Title + ", Priority: " + message.Priority.ToString();
                popupNotifier.ContentText = message.Body;
                popupNotifier.Popup();
            }, 
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            uiTaskScheduler);
    });

    connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an error opening the connection: {0}", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The connection was opened successfully");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your explanation makes perfect sense and code works, although you need to pass CancellationToken.None instead of null.

Comment: Woops, yeah my mistake on the CancellationToken. I'll fix the sample code.